# What is the essential concept behind the difference in the fundamental solutions of the Stokes and Poisson equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, electrostatics, mathematical-physics, differential-equations

The fundamental solutions, i.e., the solution with a point source, of the Poisson's equation and the Stokes equations in 3D are:

$$\nabla^2 f=\delta(\boldsymbol x) \ \Longrightarrow\ G(\boldsymbol x,\boldsymbol x_0)=-\frac{1}{4\pi|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol x_0|}$$

$$\nabla^2\boldsymbol u = \nabla P +\boldsymbol g\delta(\boldsymbol x)\ \text{  with  }\ \ \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol u=0\ \Longrightarrow\  G_{j}(\boldsymbol x,\boldsymbol x_0)=-\frac{g_{j}}{8\pi|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol x_0|}-\frac{(x-x_0)_i (x-x_0)_j g_{j}}{8\pi|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol x_0|^3}$$

Clearly this two equations have a lot in common, because their highest order differential terms have the same form. This is evidently reflected in their leading order behaviour (the term decaying as $|x-x_0|^{-1}$) in the respective fundamental solutions.

But the condition on the divergence, and the vectorial nature of the Stokes equation seem to give rise to an important correction of order $|x-x_0|^{-3}$.
Physically and/or geometrically, what are this term and the respective correction related to?
IS it the incompressibility (and how)? Is it the vectorial nature?